# Basemap - can't find .shp file

Tags: python, arcgis, matplotlib-basemap

I'm following the accepted answer from here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198530/get-lat-long-of-us-cities-and-plot-them-on-a-map-using-matplotlib-and-basemap

Those 2 lines:

```
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=32,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)
map.readshapefile('st99_d00', name='states', drawbounds=True)
```

Yilded this error:

```
OSError: cannot locate st99_d00.shp
```

I tried to understand how to add the .shp file - without success.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The files `st99_d00.dbf`, `st99_d00.shp` and `st99_d00.shx` are part of the examples available within the `basemap` project:

https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/tree/v1.3.0/examples

Since the `examples` folder is not included in a normal `basemap` installation, you will need to download these files manually from the `basemap` repository if you want to use them. Once downloaded, you need to adjust your `map.readshapefile` call based on the location where you downloaded the files.